# YUI Uploader + SSL + Firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate, yui-uploader

If your server has SSL enabled, and you're using YUI uploader, is it possible to upload using Firefox browser?

We are currently having problems with firefox but uploading with IE (7) seems to be ok.

Any ideas why it fails in Firefox (Note: the certificate was already accepted ) ?

Thanks,
Franz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to upload over HTTPS using Firefox, though I have also ran into some issues when using self-signed certificates. So you might want to check what kind of certificates you are using?

You should note that YUI uploader is using Flash and the plug-in is different for IE (ActiveX) and other browsers, which explains the different behaviors.

The IE Flash player checks for the validity of the certificate in the Windows Certificates store, hence you can make your self-signed certificate looking like a valid one.

Firefox uses its own certificate stores and I am not sure how Flash manages that (the Flash Player is the same for FF, Safari and Opera if I am correct) I have tried to import the self-signed certificates in FF but still not working for me...

So, I have the upload over SSL running correctly on Staging and Prod, but not on Dev...

I hope this information could be helpful to others...and in case I find something to make it work everywhere, I will post my solution.

Julien

Answer (score 0):

According to the [YUI Uploader cheat sheet](http://yuiblog.com/assets/pdf/cheatsheets/uploader.pdf):

> when uploading to HTTPS servers, be aware that Flash does not support self-signed certificates.